# Собрать Python, cx-Freeze и каждый модуль статикой

Tags: python, python-3.x, компиляция

Я использую [cx-freeze](/questions/tagged/cx-freeze) для распространения приложения, но оно не запускается на хостах с `glibc` со старой версией API.

Некоторые библиотеки([openssl](/questions/tagged/openssl), [msvc](/questions/tagged/msvc) на виндовс версии, libz, liblzma, libexslt, libxml2) работают если просто доложить их в папку. Но с `libpthread, libdl, libutil, libm, libc` такое не вышло.

Интересует как собрать исполнимый файл (cx-freeze) статикой, а также статически слинковать библиотеки стандартных модулей и установленных через `pip`.

Ожидаемый результат: чтоб собранное в Archlinux запустилось в Debian 6.

Начал [со сборки самого питона](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BuildStatically).

На каждый модуль выдаёт:

```
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Раздел, непредставимый для вывода
collect2: ошибка: выполнение ld завершилось с кодом возврата 1
```

UPD. Исправляется через Modules/Setup.local.
<s>Не собирается ctypes..</s>
Насильно подсунул ffi в ctypes, линковщик не видит питоновские типы.

Comment: попробуйте в docker container собирать, как это делают в [manylinux проекте](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux)